# Setting IAM Policy on a function using projects.locations.functions.setIamPolicy Gives error

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, google-iam

I'm trying to set IAM policy using projects.locations.functions.setIamPolicy, on a function which I created and deployed, but I keep receiving the following error

> GaxiosError: Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource '

Here is my code in Node.js

```js
    const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');
    const { google } = require('googleapis');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');

    function getCredentials() {
    
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'mykeyfile.json');
        console.log(filePath);
        if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(rawdata);
            return jsonData;
        }
        return null;
    
    }
    async function setPolicy() {
    
    
        try {
    
            const credentials = getCredentials();
            if (!credentials)
                return;
    
            const client = auth.fromJSON(credentials);
            client.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
    
            const cloudfunctions = await google.cloudfunctions({
                version: 'v1',
                auth: client
            });
    
            const request = {
                // REQUIRED: The resource for which the policy is being specified.
                // See the operation documentation for the appropriate value for this field.
                resource_: "projects/{myprorjectid}/locations/{zone}/functions/function-1",
    
                resource: {
                    "policy": {
                        "etag": "BwWP3fXnMuQ=",
                        "version": 1,
                        "bindings": [
                            {
                                "members": [
                                    "allUsers"
                                ],
                                "role": "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
    
                auth: client,
            };
    
                const response = (await cloudfunctions.projects.locations.functions.setIamPolicy(request)).data;
               
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
         
    
            
        } catch (err) {
    
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    setIamPolicy();
```

Any help is much appreciated. Not interested in command like options. Must be done in Node.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the service account you're using on your code doesn't have the right permissions. The error is similar to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#editor) and the solution is to add **Project Owner** or **Cloud Functions Admin** role to your service account, as both contain the `cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy` permission.